# Cocossharp CCFadeOut not working

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocossharp

I use cocossharp. I want to add fade in/out transition when replacing scene. The fade in for the second scene works fine, but the current scene's fade out is not working.

My code for transition at GameStartScene.cs is:

```
gameStartLayer.RunAction (new CCFadeOut (1.5f));
GameAppDelegate.GoToGameScene (); //director.ReplaceScene (new CCTransitionFade(1.5f, gamePlayScene));
```

How can I implement a fade out effect for the scene?

Answer (score 1):

The GoToGameScene runs immediately after the RunAction above.   Are you trying to wait until the RunAction completes before going to the game scene?

If so, make a sequence with your CCFadeOut followed by a CCDelayTime(1.5f) then run that sequence.  The other option would be a wrapping your Goto game scene in a CCCallFunc.

Answer (score 1):

jaybers is right about: "The GoToGameScene runs immediately after the RunAction above" 
BUT!
you should do this:

```
 await gameStartLayer.RunActionAsync(new CCFadeOut (1.5f));
 GameAppDelegate.GoToGameScene();
```

If you want to wait until going to next scene